# Tabela com Bootstrap não responde alguns displays

Tags: css, bootstrap-3

Estou fazendo um tabela com bootstrap, e estou testando no google chrome, só que quando coloco pra visualizar como ficaria no Iphone 5, a tabela não diminui e estoura o layout.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa Linha preta na frente da tabela, foi um border que coloquei no na Class Row, só pra mostrar o limite dela.

```css
table img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

thead tr {

  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4183D7, #22A7F0);
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;

}
.row {
  border:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Resultados da Votação</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo-padrao.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/resultado-votacao-estilo.css">
</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">

      <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Comida de Boteco</a>
          <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">Menu</button>
        </div><!-- fim navbar-header -->

        <div id="menu" class="collapse">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Início</a></li>
            <li><a href="lista-comidas.html">Lista de Comidas</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div><!-- fim menu -->

      </div><!-- fim container -->
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">

        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive text-center">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Colocação</td>
              <td>Imagem</td>
              <td>Nome</td>
              <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></td>
              <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></td>
            </tr>

          </thead>

          <tbody>

            <tr>

              <td><img src="img/medalha-ouro.png" alt="Primeiro Colocado" title="1°"></td>
              <td><img src="img/comidas/comida1.jpg" alt="imagem da comida"></td>
              <td>Hambúrguer Gourmet</td>
              <td>30 Votos</td>
              <td>10 Votos</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

              <td><img src="img/medalha-prata.png" alt="Segundo Colocado" title="1°"></td>
              <td><img src="img/comidas/comida2.jpg" alt="imagem da comida"></td>
              <td>Pizza Gourmet</td>
              <td>20 Votos</td>
              <td>15 Votos</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

              <td><img src="img/medalha-bronze.png" alt="Terceiro Colocado" title="1°"></td>
              <td><img src="img/comidas/comida3.jpg" alt="imagem da comida"></td>
              <td>Coxinha Gourmet</td>
              <td>10 Votos</td>
              <td>20 Votos</td>

            </tr>
          </tbody>

        </table>

      </div><!-- fim Col-->
    </div><!-- fim da Row-->
  </section>

  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O que ocorre é que se faz necessário ter um css diferente para diferentes navegadores, dá trabalho, porém você pode obter melhores resultados também usando media queries. para formatos de tela diferenciados.

Answer (score 0):

Como existe em diversas respostas aqui dentro do SOpt, o Bootstrap CSS possui utilitários de responsividade, o que você está fazendo errado é não indicar todos os utilitários:

Deves possuir `'col-md-* e col-lg-*'`:

```
 <section class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive text-center">
          </table>
      </div>
    </div>
 </section>
```

Repare que em `'div'` foi adicionado, `'col-md-12'` e `'col-lg-12'` para indicar responsividade em *displays* médios e grandes respectivamente.

> Agora, o seu erro se dá por quê?

Porque ao indicar `'responsive-table'`, você diz para a tabela ser responsiva em relação ao primeiro elemento pai acima, ou seja, acerca de `'<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">'`, no seu caso, ele não vai ter responsividade dentro de um display que interagiria com 'col-md-*' ou 'col-lg-*' pois não foi indicado para `'div'` possuir essas relações.

***OBS:***

Vale ressaltar que, se algo leva o tamanho para fora do tamanho permitido, ele vai estourar independente do que você faça, é necessário haver coesão do tamanho do elemento com o tamanho do conteúdo.